# How to find all the addresses using postal code in android ?

Tags: android, google-api

When I entered a postal code in my Edittext and click on a button, I need to show a address list related to that particular postal code in a Spinner.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class for your requirement.  The thing you are asking in known as reverse-geocoding.

Comment: I have alredy used Geocoder but i am not getting address like this http://www.postoffice.co.uk/postcode-finder  please check on this link ,i address list as showing on this site .

Answer (score 0):

There is service provided by google.

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=&components=postal_code:15204&sensor=false

In the URl 15204 is the postal code. Make a call to the url with the postal code in place.
This returns a json format, parse the list of cities with the postal code.

Probably first result is what you are looking for.

Comment: Through this api i am getting only one address.

Comment: Try different postal code, I don't think it will give you same address.